# why is the background color of my containing div not going across the page?

Tags: html, css

consider the following: http://jsfiddle.net/MgZ7n/10/

I want the entire hd to be highlighted in blue. That is from the left content all the way to the right content.  How do I achieve that without setting the width of the hd element to 100%.

Note: setting the width to 100% causes a strange bug in Chrome where if the browser is set at full screen, the content of the right element ends up bleeding to  the right and part of it ends up off screen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this (if you really need fixed position and no width 100%):

```
#hd {
    background-color:blue;
    position:fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MgZ7n/17/

Comment: it works well, but the Chrome bug remains. ' right:0; left:0; ' seems to have the same effect as 'width:100'  And I am having a hard time creating a reproducible sample. I will mark this as the answer since you have indeed answered the question. I will then open a new question with a better way to share the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I made this simple change:

```
#hd
{
    background-color:blue;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#right
{
    float:right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

to #HD and in chrome I don't see a bleed off.  Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgZ7n/11/)

I also changed your `span id="right"` because you float it and you set it to position fixed.  Those kind of override each other (I assume position wins).  A solution for you is to give it float: right and a margin-right: 10px.

Comment: Let me know if you still experience the bleed off.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the fixed position from the hd style in your css

```
#hd
{
    background-color:blue;
    /*position:fixed;*/
}
```

*note: there's a typo in your fiddle, in the CSS section the #left, #center style says fload instead of float

Comment: And again, this means that the position isn't fixed.

Comment: @grc The question doesn't state anywhere that the div should be fixed.

Comment: no i didnt state it. that is my bad. but this is the header that needs to stay on top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Remove position: fixed from #hd in the css. The blue will extend fully.

Comment: i need the header to stay on top of the page and not scrolled away, so this will not work as @grc noted.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the css to the following to fix your problem (deleted the fixed position on #hd and removed the fload typo):

```
#hd
{
    background-color:blue;
}
#left, #center
{
    float:left;
}
#right
{
    float:right;
    position:fixed;
    right:10px;
    top:0px;
}
```

I'm not sure what your purpose is with this layout but I think it's available for some improvements.

I would recommend using div instead of span for the 3 content columns.

When using div the elements you can style those div's according to your needs and then place the content inside those divs. With your css you can align your content divs nicely next to eachother with float or with `display: inline-block`

Comment: Once again, I'm pretty sure `position: fixed` was there for a reason.